# Django not showing image from api

Tags: python, django, image

So i'm trying to render an image from a model. The model is created successfully with the image but when I try to render it in template/home.html it doesn't show up for some reason can anybody please help me with this I would really appreciate it!

`models/Post.py`

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    body = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="posts")
    createdAt = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-createdAt', '-updatedAt']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.views import generic

from base.models import Post

# Create your views here.


class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

`templates/home.html`

```py
{% load static %}

<h1>Posts</h1>
{% for post in object_list %}
<p>{{post.title}}</p>
<img src={{post.image}} alt="Image">
<p>{{post.description}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

`settings.py`

```py
...
...
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I do not know what is happening and I would appreicete any sort of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img src={{post.image}} alt="Image"> -> <img src="{{post.image}}" alt="Image">`
There should be double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src={{post.image}} alt="Image">` is missing double quotes around the tags.

The correct code would be something like:
`<img src="{{post.image}}" alt="Image">`